# construct a url with input parameters from json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving a json response to construct a parameterized string in JavaScript. However I need to pass actual parameters from JavaScript on some properties e.g. `custom_input` has to change dynamically.

[{
"road_name_gr": "custom_input"
"town_code" : 1
}]

Then I read that json file and convert that to a url.

```
cql_filter = new URLSearchParams(json_file).toString();
```

output: `town_code=1&road_name_gr=custom_input`

However I have to "modify" the url to accept input.

e.g. `'town_code=1&road_name_gr=' + my_custom_input`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_custom_input = decodeURIComponent(my_custom_input) // URI Decode
let input_params = new URLSearchParams(json_file);
input_params.set("road_name_gr", my_custom_input);
cql_filter = input_params.toString();
```

You have to set parameter before obtain string value.

Comment: my_custom_input is in greek. I get : town_code=1&road_name_gr=%CE%A3%CE%91%CE%A1%CE%91%CE%A3 . Also it should not set, it should replace.

Comment: The set method overwrites existing field.

Comment: Try this: my_custom_input = decodeURIComponent(my_custom_input) on top of block.